# Compaq Q2009 monitor display Issues

Tags: display, lcd

I have this compaq q2009 monitor 20' inches and I am having display issues. When I turn on the computer the image is displayed fine for a fraction of a second and then the display goes black. If I turn off the monitor and turn it on again the the same thing happens: the image is displayed for a fraction of a second and then goes black. This is odd. I've looked all over the web and I haven't found anything useful (not even in the HP website). So there is no "out of range" or "recommended resolution" message. It just displays and then goes black. I think the resolution is fine because it was working OK until recently and I haven't changed anything in that regard. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK to start with we have a Compaq Q2009 20" LCD Monitor [(Product Specifications Here)](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01732380&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=nz&lang=en&product=3894555) 
For my money I would say that it sounds like a backlight problem.  There is a fairly thorough troubleshooting guide from HP for “A monitor is connected to the computer and has power but does not display anything” [HERE](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=nz&lang=en&product=3894555&docname=bph04760). However another step that is not mentioned, that you may want to try first, is shining a flashlight into the monitor at an oblique angle.  If you can see the normal screen but very dim your backlight/ballast is dead and the monitor will have to be repaired/replaced.

Comment: I saw this answer too late. And the monitor was already replaced. so I had no way to test this. Anyway, thanks for your help. +1